# two different links show/hide div with two IDs. How?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a series of questions, based on responses I am showing/hiding the next questions (kinda like the 'create your own adventure' stories). Here is my HTML:

```
<!-- TIER 3
================================================== -->
<!--From Steak/Fries-->
<div id="SteakFries" class="hide">
    <p>I'd rather...</p>
    <span class="responseRead"><img class="prompt" src="http://fakeimg.pl/50" data-respnseto="Read">Read a Best-Seller on the Beach</span>
    <span class="responseExplore"><img class="prompt" src="http://fakeimg.pl/50" data-respnseto="Explore">Explore Ancient Ruins &amp; Natural Wonders</span>
</div>

<!--From Chamagne/Caviar
To travel style-->

<!--From Gastro-->
<div id="GastroPubs" class="hide">
    <p>I'd rather...</p>
    <span class="responseExplore"><img class="prompt" src="http://fakeimg.pl/50" data-respnseto="Explore">Explore Ancient Ruins &amp; Natural Wonders</span>
    <span class="responseVisitCity"><img class="prompt" src="http://fakeimg.pl/50" data-respnseto="VisitCity">Visit City Landmarks &amp; Theatres</span>
</div>

<!--From Wine/Cheese-->
<div id="GastroPubs" class="hide">
    <p>I'd rather...</p>
    <span class="responseVisitCity"><img class="prompt" src="http://fakeimg.pl/50" data-respnseto="VisitCity">Visit City Landmarks &amp; Theatres</span>
    <span class="responseRelaxParadise"><img class="prompt" src="http://fakeimg.pl/50" data-respnseto="RelaxParadise">Relax in an Over-Water Bungalo in Paradise</span>
</div>

<!--opens these divs-->
<!-- TIER 4 (Styles Discover)
================================================== -->
<!--From VisitCity-->
<div id="VisitCity" class="culturalChameleon hide">
    Cultural Chameleon
</div>

<!--From Champagne/VisitCity-->
<div id="RelaxParadise" class="fiveStar hide">
    Five-Star Fanatic
</div>

<!--From Explore-->
<div id="Explore" class="activeAdventurer hide">
    Active Adventurer
</div>

<!--From Read/VisitCity-->
<div id="Read VisitCity" class="sunSeeker hide">
    Sun Seeker
</div>
<!--================================================== -->
</div>
```

So, based on the link in Tier 3 - the corresponding div in Tier 4 is displayed.

Here is my jQuery:

```
var data = "";
$('.prompt').click(function(){
    data = $(this).attr('data-respnseto');
    console.log(data);
    $('.hide').hide();

    $('#' + data).fadeIn(600);
});
```

It works fine, until I try to display the last item in tier 4. See, it becomes visible by clicking either the:

```
data-respnseto="Read"
data-respnseto="VisitCity"
```

items in Tier 3. However, the way I am doing it - I am only looking for one ID. Any ideas on how I can display item 4 in Tier 4 when the user clicks either of the links in tier 3.

Makes sense? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: ids are allowed to have spaces?

Comment: Also, `$(this).attr('data-respnseto'); == $(this).data('respnseto');`

Comment: did you mean something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/texg4fax/ if yest let me know to post it as answer with more details.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look. Not quite. I think seeing the entire code will help. http://jsfiddle.net/n8gtzgvL/

If you click on comfy/casual > Tropical Drinks & Poolside Cabanas, the following div should be displayed:

`<div id="Read TropicalPoolside" class="sunSeeker hide">
    Sun Seeker
</div>`

Comment: Actually, that is exactly what I needed. My syntax was bad, but your code got it working. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var data = "";
$('.prompt').click(function(){
    data = $(this).data('respnseto');
    console.log(data);
    $('.hide').hide();

    $("div[id*='"+ data + "']").fadeIn(600);
});
```

**[Check JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/texg4fax/)**